# How do i update e2fsck?

Tags: boot, 16.04, 64-bit, badblocks

Recently, after a sudden power failure, my 1tb hard drive (/dev/sda1) failed and will not mount. It says, ``` Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/zangar_/4b84d62b-520d-408e-addc-7a2bf52cc4e3: Command-line ``mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sda1" "/media/zangar_/4b84d62b-520d-408e-addc-7a2bf52cc4e3"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error ```

```
   `In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.`
```

I tried `e2fsck` but it asks me to `Get a newer version of e2fsck!`
Then, I looked at all the other posts about updating e2fsck ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747656/ext4-broken-file-system-on-ubuntu-14-04-4/755376) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121987/superblock-errors).) These answers did not work for me.
   [image: My problem!]

Any help is greatly appreciated, as i have time sensitive documents in the unmountable drive.

Comment: See [ext4 broken file system on ubuntu 14.04.4](http://askubuntu.com/a/868737/178692)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB 16.10 (prefer DVD). It must be 16.10 or higher.

Open a `terminal` and type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`.

Now you may be able to mount the drive as normal.

Answer (score 10):

Using a live CD/DVD/USB seems like a workaround that may not be always applicable.

I believe that the correct answer how to have e2fsck updated is to compile latest version from the sources.

1. Download the latest version (1.44.3) from http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/ and unpack in a directory and `cd` into it.
2. According to the INSTALL document:

   ```
    mkdir build; cd build
    ../configure
    make
    sudo make install
   ```
3. Check that you have new version now:

   ```
    $ e2fsck -V
    e2fsck 1.44.3 (10-July-2018)
    Using EXT2FS Library version 1.44.3, 10-July-2018
   ```

Note: you may need to install compiler and tools with `apt get install gcc`.

UPDATE 09/2020: Above link is official ext2fs informational microsite (non https protected), lastest sources are securely hosted on https://sourceforge.net/projects/e2fsprogs/. BTW author announced: "All users of e2fsprogs are urged to upgrade to the 1.45.6 version as soon as possible".

Comment: While this may be an excellent answer otherwise, please note that the SourceForge link to the latest version uses the insecure HTTP protocol and as far as I am concerned it would be highly advisable to replace it with a more secure option (replacing the protocol part of the url doesn't work unfortunately). Partly flagging this up as I'm just humbly looking for the solution while you might have a slightly better looking link at hand :)

Comment: Thanks @brezniczky for comment, I've added an update to the answer

Comment: Thank you @VasekCh!